# How to check for instantiation of a python class during unit-tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I for the life of me can not remember how to test for the instination of a python class.

It was something like:

```
try:
  m = MyModel()
except:
  ...
```

I can't remember the exception to call or the assert to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common exception to use for failed instantiation.  The constructor (both `__init__` and `__new__`) can raise any exception it wants.  The `except` statement you have without an explicit exception will catch every type of exception, which *may* be what you want.

Comment: Yeah the except statement is currently `except Exception:` to achieve the same as without naming the exception with `assert(False, "Object didn't initialize")`, but still not 100% sold on this. I'll work with it, thanks.   I don't want to override `__init__` or `__new__` in this case because it's for a django Model (which uses lots of voodoo underneath to achieve it's goals).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, however here is a list of all built in exceptions for Python (2.7):

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html

Hope this helps.